# Convert ARRAY<STRUCT> to multiple columns in BigQuery SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to convert Array< struct > to multiple columns.
The data structure looks like:

```
column name: Parameter
[
  -{
      key: "Publisher_name"
      value: "Rubicon"
   }
  -{
      key: "device_type"
      value: "IDFA"
   }
  -{
      key: "device_id"
      value: "AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD"
   }
]
```

What I want to get:

```
publisher_name  device_type  device_id
Rubicon         IDFA         AAAA-BBBB-CCCC-DDDD
```

I have tried this which  caused the duplicates of other columns.

```
select h from table unnest(parameter) as h
```

BTW, I am very curious why do we want to use this kind of structure in Bigquery. Can't we just add the above 3 columns into table?

Comment: I'm confused by the array - in BigQuery the schema of each struct has to be the same within one array. Other keys get overwritten, other types are not even possible.

Comment: what you mean by confusion - the schema here looks to me simple / clear  - ARRAY<STRUCT<key STRING, value STRING>>

Comment: aah .. key is a key and value is a key ... well .. that's confusing for me :D got it now, thanks

Comment: yes, at least this is how i read the question :o)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(Parameter) WHERE key = 'Publisher_name') AS Publisher_name,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(Parameter) WHERE key = 'device_type') AS device_type,
  (SELECT value FROM UNNEST(Parameter) WHERE key = 'device_id') AS device_id
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

You can further refactor code by using SQL UDF as below

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION getValue(k STRING, arr ANY TYPE) AS
((SELECT value FROM UNNEST(arr) WHERE key = k));
SELECT 
  getValue('Publisher_name', Parameter) AS Publisher_name,
  getValue('device_type', Parameter) AS device_type,
  getValue('device_id', Parameter) AS device_id
FROM `project.dataset.table`
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. It works perfectly. Btw, do you know what the benefit is to use this kind of structure instead adding these columns into the  table?

Comment: i think it really depends on your use case. if you end up with pivoting anyway  - why not to have this in separate columns from the very beginning? still it is totally depends on your use case

Comment: the benefit of having array here can be in case if you do have number of aother columns - now they are stored just once per row - but if you will be storing your array's structs as columns  - you will need to store redundant data for other columns and this will be extra cost

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant i found this thread and am having a similar question. In my case my array of struct could have over 100 key values: key_1, ..., key_100 for example. In this case what's an efficient way to proceed other than call the function getValue 100 times?

Answer (score 1):

To convert to multiple columns, you will need to aggregate, something like this:

```
select ?,
       max(case when pv.parameter = 'Publisher_name' then value end) as Publisher_name,
       max(case when pv.parameter = 'device_type' then value end) as device_type,
       max(case when pv.parameter = 'device_id' then value end) as device_id
from t cross join
     unnest(parameter) pv
group by ?
```

You need to explicitly list the new columns that you want.  The `?` is for the columns that remain the same.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. It works perfectly! Btw, do you know what the benefit is to use this kind of structure instead adding these columns into the table?

Comment: @DavidD . . . The parameter/value pairs can differ from row-to-row.  I would (and actually do) use JSON for this purpose.  I think it more flexible because the "value" doesn't have to be a string.